# Adding values to combobox from client side in WPF application + keeping combo values in application locally after closing

Tags: c#, list, combobox, application-settings

I have following code in my WPF application where I fill combobox, so when I run application, combobox is already prefilled:

```
        combo.Items.Add("first");
        combo.Items.Add("second");
        combo.Items.Add("third");
```

Is there anyway I can add values to combobox from client side? I mean, I run application, then for example double click on combobox, start typing some value, hit enter, it saves that value and its forever added to combobox? I would like to implement this feature, but I just dont know how.

EDIT: Okay we fixed first issue. I want to ask one more question. How can I do it if I want to add new link and have it in combobox forever? Next time I start app again, my added links are gone :( I want to have them here till I delete them. Am I able to do it without database? Just in application background?

EDIT2: I discovered application setting, am I somehow able to maintain list of values, which will fill combobox and I will also add values from GUI and when I exit app, this updated list will save in setting, so next time it will open with updated combobox? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: It's called a database or an external file.

Comment: You never mentioned what kind of client you intend to do this for.

Comment: ahh sorry guys, I just do a small WPF app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some sort of `TextBox` to enter the new text. As for getting the typed-in text to the `ComboBox`, having an "add" button is going to be easiest, but you can also check for the ENTER key in the `KeyUp` event of the `TextBox`.

In the click event handler of the `Button` or the `KeyUp` event handler of the `TextBox`, whichever route you decide to go, you just add the new item:

```
combo.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. :) I want to ask one more question. How can I do it if I want to add new link and have it in combobox forever? Next time I start app again, my added links are gone :( I want to have them here till I delete them. Am I able to do it without database? Just in application background? Thanks

Comment: @Jacob Nope, you'll have to save the new items somewhere. Not necessarily a database, but some form of long term storage: database, text file, registry, etc.